# multiple groupby using operator in linq display differently from using expression

Tags: linq

I am learning Linq by reading Linq in Action book. On chapter 5 where the author performs multiple grouping. The linq expression is as follow:

```
var query =
  from book in SampleData.Books
  group new {book.Title, book.Publisher.Name} by book.Subject into grouping
  select new {Subject=grouping.Key.Name, Books=grouping};
```

The output from author is: [image]

I am rewriting by using operator instead of expression. I tried with this but the result showing in LinqPad is not the same as the above:

```
var query2 = SampleData.Books.GroupBy(
                book => new {book.Subject}
            )
            .Select(book => new {
                    Subject = book.Key.Subject.Name, 
                    Children = book.GroupBy(b => new {b.Subject.Description, b.Subject.Name})}
            );
```

This is my output: [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first query performs a single groupBy, the second performs two nested groupBy.

To accurately represent the first query in method syntax, you need the [overload of GroupBy that takes two parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534304(v=vs.100).aspx), one to pick the key for each element, and one to pick the representation of each element within the group

```
.GroupBy(book => book.Subject, book => new {book.Title, book.Publisher.Name} )
```

(Note that you do not need to create an anonymous object with only one member: `book => book.Subject` works just as well as `book => new{book.Subject}`

Then you can perform the final select over the result of the GroupBy operator:

```
.Select(grouping => new {Subject=grouping.Key.Name, Books=grouping});
```

You can also do this all with only the GroupBy command, if you use this even more obscure [GroupBy overload that takes three parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534493(v=vs.100).aspx): key-selector, element-selector and result-selector:

```
.GroupBy(book => book.Subject,  
                 // select a key
         book => new {book.Title, book.Publisher.Name},
                 // select the elements of each group
         grouping => new {Subject=grouping.Key.Name, Books=grouping} ) 
                 // select the final result
```

This does exactly the same as the previous two commands combined.